# If I click on any tab then all its predecessor tabs gets loaded.How can I stop this

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I even set `dynamic='true'`.

Here's my code :

```
<p:tabView onTabChange="handleTabChange(event,index)" id="CRE_CI" widgetVar="TabV" prependId="false" cache="false" dynamic="true">
            <p:ajax event="tabChange" oncomplete="hideTabs()" update=":CRE_CI" />
            <p:tab id="CS" title="Customer Search" style="outline: 0;">
                <ui:include src="Customer_Search//CustomerSearch.xhtml" />
            </p:tab>
            <p:tab title="Individual" style="outline: 0;">
                <p:tabView id="PFS" prependId="false" cache="false" dynamic="true">
                    <p:tab title="Personal Financial Statement" style="outline: 0;">
                        <ui:include src="PFS//Personal_Finance.xhtml" />
                    </p:tab>
                </p:tabView>
            </p:tab>
            <p:tab title="Business" style="outline: 0;">
                <p:tabView id="Busi" prependId="false" cache="false" dynamic="true">
                    <p:tab title="C&amp;I" style="outline: 0;">
                        <p:tabView id="CI" prependId="false" cache="false" dynamic="true">
                            <p:tab title="CI Balance Sheet" style="outline: 0;">
                                <ui:include src="CI//CI_Balance_Sheet.xhtml" /> 
                            </p:tab>
                            <p:tab title="CI Income Statement" style="outline: 0;">
                                <ui:include src="CI//CI_Income_Statement.xhtml" />
                            </p:tab> 
                            <p:tab title="CI Retained Earnings"  style="outline: 0;">
                                <ui:include src="CI//CI_Earning_Statement.xhtml" />
                            </p:tab>
                            <p:tab title="UCA Cash Flow" style="outline: 0;">
                                <ui:include src="CI//CI_Cash_Flow.xhtml" />
                            </p:tab>
                            <p:tab title="Ratios" style="outline: 0;">
                                <ui:include src="CI//CI_Ratios.xhtml" />
                            </p:tab>
                            <p:tab title="Proposed Trad. Cash Flow" style="outline: 0;">
                                <ui:include src="CI//CI_Proposed_CashFlow.xhtml" />
                            </p:tab>
                            <p:tab title="Proposed UCA Cash Flow" style="outline: 0;">
                                <ui:include src="CI//CI_PropUCA_CashFlow.xhtml" />
                            </p:tab>
                            <p:tab title="Stress Test-Sales Expenses" style="outline: 0;">
                                <ui:include src="CI//CI_StressTest_Sales.xhtml" />
                            </p:tab>
                            <p:tab title="Stress Test-Interest Rates" style="outline: 0;">
                                <ui:include src="CI//CI_StressTest_InterestRate.xhtml" />
                            </p:tab>
                        </p:tabView>
                    </p:tab>
                    <p:tab title="CRE" style="outline: 0;">
                        <p:tabView id="CRE" prependId="false" cache="false" dynamic="true">
                            <p:tab title="CRE Residential Input" style="outline: 0;">
                                <ui:include src="CRE//CRE_Residential_Inputs.xhtml" />
                            </p:tab>
                            <p:tab title="CRE Commercial Analysis" style="outline: 0;">
                                <ui:include src="CRE//CRE_Commercial_Analysis.xhtml" />
                            </p:tab>
                            <p:tab title="CRE Financials" style="outline: 0;">
                                <ui:include src="CRE//CRE_Financials.xhtml" />
                            </p:tab>
                            <p:tab title="Amortization Table" style="outline: 0;">
                                <ui:include src="CRE//CRE_Amortization_Table.xhtml" />
                            </p:tab>
                            <p:tab title="Stress Test" style="outline: 0;">
                                <ui:include src="CRE//CRE_Stress_Test.xhtml" />
                            </p:tab>
                            <p:tab title="Risk Analysis" style="outline: 0;">
                                <ui:include src="CRE//CRE_Risk_Analysis.xhtml" />
                            </p:tab>
                            <p:tab title="Debt Yield Analysis" style="outline: 0;">
                                <ui:include src="CRE//CRE_DebtYield_Analysis.xhtml" />
                            </p:tab>
                            <p:tab title="Rent Roll Summary" style="outline: 0;">
                                <ui:include src="CRE//CRE_RentRoll_Summary.xhtml" />
                            </p:tab>
                        </p:tabView>
                    </p:tab>
                </p:tabView>
            </p:tab>
            <p:tab title="Global Cash Flow" style="outline: 0;">
                <ui:include src="CRE//CRE_Global_CashFlow.xhtml" />
            </p:tab>
        </p:tabView>
```

Comment: please read [How to ask ?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Which version of primefaces? any successor tabs are not reloaded?

Comment: and please create a [mcve]. Are the `ui:include`s relevant? If not replace them with som plain text. Are the number of tabs relevant? If not, replace them with two or three. Is the javascript onTabChange and the oncomlete relevant? If not, remove them, If they are, include their code, but try to minimize that to. And rephrase your question then to